# SQL update multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query that works for updating the value from one column with the value that the user enters with php...How can i rewrite it to update multiple values ??

```
UPDATE  `lahiguera_hor`.`cupos` 
SET  `cuposLun8`='$_POST[cupolun8]'   
WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun8` =  '$cupolun8';
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: See docs first [**UPDATE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: You appear wide open to [SQL Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/3396), beyond your current problem.  Use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/812837), or suffer the consequences.  Note that generally columns with numbers in them indicate potential design problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 UPDATE  `lahiguera_hor`.`cupos` SET  
`cuposLun8`='$_POST[cupolun8]',
 `AdditonalCol1`='$_POST[AdditonalCol1]',
 `AdditonalCol2`='$_POST[AdditonalCol2]'
 WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun8` =  '$cupolun8';
```

Set columns should be separated with a comma.

Comment: I tried this :

UPDATE  `lahiguera_hor`.`cupos` SET  `cuposLun8`='$_POST[cupolun8]',`cuposLun10`='$_POST[cupolun10]'   WHERE  `cupos`.`cuposLun8` =  '$cupolun8', `cuposLun10` =  '$cupolun10';

But didnt work!

Comment: the error resides in your where clause.  You would need AND as you're providing two qualifiers:  WHERE  cupos.cuposLun8 = '$cupolun8' AND cuposLun10 = '$cupolun10';

Comment: It works fine!! Should it work also for more than 2? if i add more using AND?

Comment: It will work for as many columns you would like. You can also load up on the and statements as well.  if this was the proper solution, can you please mark it as such?